# equivs-build: fatal error occurred while parsing debian/changelog

Tags: packaging, equivs

There is no `debian/changelog` file involved when using `equivs-build`, so would the `fatal error occurred while parsing debian/changelog` error be a bug?

Here are the details:

```
$ cat ttf-ubuntu-font-family 
Package: ttf-ubuntu-font-family
Architecture: all
Version: 91:0.83-2
Multi-Arch: foreign
Priority: optional
Section: universe/oldlibs
Source: fonts-ubuntu (0.83-2)
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Fonts Task Force <pkg-fonts-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 40
Depends: fonts-ubuntu
Homepage: https://design.ubuntu.com/font/
Description: sans-serif font set from Ubuntu (transitional package) (equ-dummy)
Task: kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, lubuntu-live-share, core-share, lubuntu-gtk-core, lubuntu-desktop-share, lubuntu-core, lubuntu-live, lubuntu-qt-core, lubuntu-live-qt, lubuntu-live-gtk

$ equivs-build ttf-ubuntu-font-family
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_prep
dh_testdir
dh_testroot
dh_install
dh_installdocs
dh_installchangelogs
dh_installchangelogs: warning:     debian/changelog(l2): found end of file where expected first heading
dh_installchangelogs: error: fatal error occurred while parsing debian/changelog
debian/rules:20: recipe for target 'binary-indep' failed
make: *** [binary-indep] Error 255
Error in the build process: exit status 2

$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:        18.04

$ apt-cache policy equivs
equivs:
  Installed: 2.1.0
  Candidate: 2.1.0
  Version table:
 *** 2.1.0 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `debian/changelog` with `dch --create`  (from `devscripts` package)
and fill the changelog template created with package name, version, and distribution.
(on later package version, you'd use `dch -i` to add new changelog entries and update the version)

Also, for some reason, I had to comment out 'Source:' line in file I run `equivs-build` on, then it worked without `dh_installchangelogs` throwing errors.

Comment: Thanks Matija, I'll get back to you in about a month as I'm traveling and can't access my build environment now...

Comment: 1000 thanks for this entry, working fine for me, thaaannkkksss